# Why IntelliJ won't debug in some cases with an error. Example attached

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was testing something and ran across a curious case of IntelliJ not debugging my code when I have a breakpoint as shown in Image 1. But when I move the breakpoint, works fine.

The code:

```
public class Walrus {
    public int weight;
    public double tuskSize;

    public Walrus(int weight, int x){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.tuskSize = tuskSize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Random declared ints.
        int x;
        double y;
// Declared a Walrus
        Walrus someWalrus;
// Set to null
        someWalrus = null;
// Initialize a new Walrus.
        Walrus a = new Walrus(10,3);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

When I have my debug point here (see figure), this does not work and gives the following error:

[image: The debug point]

Error:

*Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59776', transport: 'socket'
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59776', transport: 'socket'
Process finished with exit code 0*

Now, if I do this (see 2nd image), it runs fine:

[image: It runs for this.]

I guess maybe it thinks that there's nothing to debug, as I have not assigned any of the variables. But that's just a guess. Could someone please explain what is happening here under the hood? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once the program is executed, the first breakpoint disables as "No executable code found". See
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain why isn't it executable? Because I read that when you only declare a variable, roughly speaking, Java searches for some memory in computer, and reserves it. For example, for int x; it reserves a memory of 32 bits, which we cannot access ofcourse, but it did something, so didn't it execute this statement?

Comment: Memory reservation happens before the moment debugger can connect to the running java process. It's the compiler's job.